# How to extract parameters from response url in Jmeter

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing

I've an isssue. I run a test plan in jmeter. I've a http request, response header has a URL with 1 parameter (Ex: response header => URL: http://abc.xyz?code=xxx). Now I want to get the value of parameter "code", and put it into the body of next http request. How can I do that? Please help. Sr if my English not good enough

Answer (score 0):

If I'm correctly getting your requirement and you need to extract the code from a [response header](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers#response_context) which looks like this:

You can do it using a [Regular Expression Extractor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Regular_Expression_Extractor) configured like:

[image]

End-to-end demo:

[image]

More information:

- [JMeter: Regular Expressions](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/regular_expressions.html)
- [Using RegEx (Regular Expression Extractor) with JMeter](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/207421325-Using-RegEx-Regular-Expression-Extractor-with-JMeter)
- [Perl 5 Regex Cheat sheet](https://perlmaven.com/regex-cheat-sheet)